# How to fix this navigation bar JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

I tried to make a navigation bar in a webpage using this JavaScript code snippet

```js
sections.forEach((elem, index) => {
  let textlink = elem.getAttribute("data-nav");
  let textnode = document.createTextNode(textlink);
  let newli = document.createElement("li");
  let newlink = document.createElement("a");
  
  newlink.appendChild(textnode);
  newli.appendChild(newlink);
  newlink.addEventListener("click", () => {
    elem.scrollIntoView({
      behaviour: "smooth"
    });
  })
  
  fragment.appendChild(newli);
})

myul.appendChild(fragment);
```

But the navigation bar never appears... I tried not to include the anchor element in the code, and to  put the anchor element after the list element, and tried using `let` and `const` instead of `var`, still no use.
Any help?

Comment: Please include more context

Comment: Please check if you have any error details in the console browser. If so, [edit] your question and add the error details.

Comment: Where is `fragment` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what `sections`, `fragment`, and `myul` refer to. Here is a sample HTML markup that works for the provided script. There is some CSS here to, that shows-off some flex-box.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
const myul = document.querySelector('.nav');

sections.forEach((elem, index) => {
  let textlink = elem.getAttribute("data-nav");
  let textnode = document.createTextNode(textlink);
  let newli = document.createElement("li");
  let newlink = document.createElement("a");

  newlink.appendChild(textnode);
  newli.appendChild(newlink);
  newlink.addEventListener("click", () => {
    elem.scrollIntoView({
      behaviour: "smooth"
    });
  })

  fragment.appendChild(newli);
})

myul.appendChild(fragment);

// Ipsum
document.querySelectorAll('.ipsum').forEach(p =>
  fetch('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(paragraphs => p.innerHTML = paragraphs.map(p => `<p>${p}</p>`).join('')));
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


header {
  font-size: 1.33em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0.33em;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.nav li {
  margin: 0.5em 1em;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav li:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<header>My Website</header>
<ul class="nav"></ul>
<main>
  <section data-nav="Main" id="main">
    <h1>Main</h1>
    <div class="ipsum"></div>
  </section>
  <section data-nav="About us" id="about-us">
    <h1>About us</h1>
    <div class="ipsum"></div>
  </section>
  <section data-nav="Help" id="help">
    <h1>Help</h1>
    <div class="ipsum"></div>
  </section>
</main>
```